# Navigation from OnDoubleTapped method

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, controls, pushpin

I've created a customized Pushpin ( Windows store) and i need to navigate whenever the control double tapped/clicked

So i figured out that `OnDoubleTapped(DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)` will do it,but when i tried .. it didn't work.
The following code is from the Control code-behind

```
protected async override void OnDoubleTapped(DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDoubleTapped(e);
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Target)); //Frame has no Navigate()
        }
```

Comment: I would be good if you mentioned type of the Control you are overriding it's method.

Comment: The control: Pushpin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using a dispatcher :

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
            {
                Frame thisFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();
                thisFrame.Navigate(typeof(Target));
            }));
```